# Exception 'module has no attribute connector' - Python mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm just attempting to add some data in bulk.

I firstly connect then iterate through dictionary items, creating each query to update the zip_ids table, which is mysql based. Below is how I am doing this:

```
connection = _mysql.connect(host="xxx",user = "user", passwd="123", db="mine")
for id, zip in id_zip.items():
    query += """UPDATE zip_ids SET zip = %s id = %s;"""% (zip,id) 
print query    
try:
    cur = connection.cursor()
    connection.execute(query, multi=True)
    connection.commit()
    cur.close()
    connection.close()
    connection.disconnect()
except _mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print 'issue in Execution of adding zip', str(e)
```

Issue is that I keep getting an exception thrown:

`Exception 'module' object has no attribute 'connector'`

How can I resolve this exception? What is its cause? Is the code for adding data in bulk correct?

Comment: What is `_msql` here? Where is that imported from? Presumably the `except _mysql.connector.Error as err:` line is throwing the exception, so you need to tell us more about where that module comes from.

Comment: forgot to `import mysql.connector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you that the `_mysql` module has no attribute named `connector`.

I usually use ipython to learn about modules I know nothing about.

```
In [1]: import _mysql
In [2]: _mysql.conn
```

Then I hit the tab key to see what auto completes and I get

```
_mysql.connect     _mysql.connection
```

Tab-completing on `_mysql.connection.` shows me that `_mysql.connection.error` exists. Then I do

```
In [4]: ?_mysql.connection.error
Type:       method_descriptor
String Form:<method 'error' of '_mysql.connection' objects>
Docstring:
Returns the error message for the most recently invoked API function
that can succeed or fail. An empty string () is returned if no error
occurred.
```

As for adding bulk data, I think you're mixing up the APIs of two different python modules. You're using `_mysql` but I think what you really want is `MySQLdb`: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Hope this helps!