# AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu-16.04, mysql-python

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, trying to connect to mysql in python:

```
    import mysql
    username = 'root'

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=username, database='db')
    cnx.close()
```

But I get an error:

```
    File "pysql1.py", line 4, in <module>
      cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=username, database='db')
    AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'
```

I installed the mysql python module by downloading the package [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/). I tried `sudo apt-get install python-mysql.connector` to no avail. Any pointers?

EDIT: after adding `import mysql.connector` I got an unrelated permissions error which I've now resolved, so that's what I needed ty lots!!!

Comment: try with `import mysql.connector`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception 'module has no attribute connector' - Python mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062113/exception-module-has-no-attribute-connector-python-mysql)

Comment: @kev1n91 that seems to be about `_mysql` which I've never heard of. At the end of the top answer they suggest there's some confusion over libraries

Comment: Nevertheless, the solution shows a way which might solve this issue too: 
Have you tried to include it in IPython (Spyder or sth similiar) and see with tab auto-completion if connector is maybe available?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562532/mysql-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-unpack-from

Comment: `print(dir(mysql))` and give the result.

Comment: @roganjosh `print(dir(mysql))` gives `['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'connector']`

Comment: @planpony69 i'm curious about what command you're using to avoid password in the terminal ?

Comment: @PRMoureu `mysql -u root`: I just set a blank password and stepped through the steps in link below to not have to use `sudo`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost"

Comment: Glad you found a solution, do you still need to input the password ?

Comment: @PRMoureu No, ty. I hadn't properly completed the steps in my OWN link :o Following those instructions properly resolved the issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is to execute :

```
import mysql.connector # or from mysql import connector
```

Because the module `connector` is only available when you import it explicitly :

```
import mysql

print(dir(mysql))
>>> ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', 
'__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

import mysql.connector

print(dir(mysql))
>>> ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', 
'__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'connector']
```

---

The `__init__` file in the module `mysql` doesn't import the module `connector`.

```
mysql
|_______ __init__.py # no import at this level
|_______ connector
         |________ __init__.py
```

This could work implicitly if `connector` was imported inside `__init__` with : `from . import connector`.

Comment: Which makes me wonder why they didn't implement it that way in the first place, but I guess you're not answerable to that :)

Answer (score 11):

I was still getting the same error after `import mysql.connector` and checking permissions. I was running my script on MacOS using bash. After hours of searching for a solution, came across this post on the mysql forums: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?50,584171,584729#msg-584729

The poster mentions that your python script can't be named `mysql.py` My script was named `types.py`, so I renamed it to `setup-types.py` and that solved my problem. Hopefully this saves others some time when dealing with this same error.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to python as well, this is probably a common mistake

Comment: I had another script named "select.py" in the same folder which also lead to  «No module named 'Connection'»

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed both  ***mysql-connector*** and ***mysql-connector-python***:

1. **uninstall** mysql-connector-python
2. **uninstall** mysql-connector
3. **reinstall** mysql-connector-python

If your file is named **mysql.py** or **select.py** rename it.

Comment: this works for those who installed both mysql-connector and mysql-connector-python together

Answer (score 4):

I had "pip install"ed mysql-connector before installing mysql-connector-python.  I uninstalled the mysql-connector, and was getting this error.

As this stackoverflow question/answer mentions, uninstalling and then reinstalling the mysql-connector-python had everything working.

[Python | MySQL | AttributeError: module 'mysql.connector' has no attribute 'connect'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176479/python-mysql-attributeerror-module-mysql-connector-has-no-attribute-conn)

Answer (score 2):

One more observation. In many tutorials, they didn't installed the python connector the same way. At those times, the import statement might be the cause of the issue. Try the below import statement.

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
```

Comment: IMHO, renaming a property of a module to the module itself is a horrible idea. This could easily confuse someone why `mysql` does/doesn't have the expected properties/methods available. Better to use something like `import mysql.connnector as mysqlConnector` or just `import mysql.connector`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I created a script called "select.py" I renamed it and it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
import mysql.connector as mysql

connection = mysql.connect(
   host="localhost", user="root", port='3306', database="database_name")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but none of the above solutions worked for me. I unfortunately had to try something else. I found out that the package I used wasn't working anymore. It must have been a mix-up, where I upgraded my package and so my script wasn't working anymore.

However, I installed this package: https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/ and my script is now back up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I am using python xenv to connect to the mysql outside the virtual env. After trying to fix the error below a lot of times:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/py/p.py", line 5, in <module>
    db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'mysql.connector' has no attribute 'connect'
```

The issue is finally fixed by upgrading my mac OS system, uninstalling mysql-connector-python and mysql-connector, and reinstalling the mysql-connector-python.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred for me (even after `pip install mysql-connector-python`) when attempting to run `db = mysql.connector.connect(...)` in the Python IDLE Shell. When I switched to a full `.py` file, it worked correctly with the same code. I assume this has to do with what other users have mentioned about forbidden file names.

I believe if you can run `import mysql`, check that `'connector' in dir(mysql) == True`, and run `import mysql.connector` without errors, it means that it must be something other than a problem with your `mysql-connector-python` package, like this.