# module 'mysql.connector' has no attribute 'connect' - Python - Raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have a simple program, which it saved data to mysql.
The program writes corectly to database when it runing on local ssh window.
When i tried started program by autostart (.bashrc).

I getting this problem:

```
module 'mysql.connector' has no attribute 'connect'
```

I use mysql connector to connect with my database.

I tried run programs other methods of autostart, but i had the same problem.

Comment: I think you might be using a different python environment. Check the installed package in both scenarios via pip. Maybe this answer helps:https://stackoverflow.com/a/61252423/12769783