# module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector', trying to connect mysql to python (spyder 3.8)

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I've been trying to connect Python and MySql but I keep getting errors. This is my code:

```py
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect( 
    host="localhost", 
    user="kdvis", 
    password="root")
    
print (mydb)
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\kdvis\Desktop\flies\11\python\connection1.py", line 9, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    
    AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'
```

I've reconfigured MySql, gotten a `caching_sha2_password` error, a `sha256` password requires SSL error, an access denied for `user@localhost` error, tried to change my root password using alter keyword on MySql, and read almost every solution but none worked.
Help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Try to update it first: 'python -m pip install mysql-connector-python --upgrade' and do you have python 2 or 3? Because I tried it with Python 3 and it works.

Comment: @Nexarius It says that the requirement is already satisfied. (Python 3.8, I mentioned it in the heading)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503776/attributeerror-module-mysql-has-no-attribute-connector)

Comment: @sahasrara62 thanks, but no I've visited the page 3 times

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed mysql as from pip.
If from other source remove it and install it from pip using coomand.

```
pip install mysql
```

Comment: i have, thanks. it should be pip install mysql-connector-python, i think